# The DS.Model `relationships` property is unavailable in record's `init`?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Official [documentation for DS.Model](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html) describes:

- [method `eachRelationship`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_eachRelationship)
- [property `relationships`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_relationships)

When i do:

```
App.Parent = DS.Model.extend({
  children: DS.hasMany('child'),
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    this.eachRelationship(function(foo, bar, baz) {
      console.log('each relationship', foo, bar, baz);
    });
  }
});
```

...it prints out the `children` relationship.

However, when i do:

```
App.Parent = DS.Model.extend({
  children: DS.hasMany('child'),
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    console.log('realtionships', this.get('relationships'));
  }
});
```

...it prints `undefined`!

Why? How do i access the `relationships` property during record initialization, without reverting to the `eachRelationship` method?

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vapama/9/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `_relationships` (with an underscore) property available that is an `Object`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nudor/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`relationships` is defined on the class not on the instances (The static next to the property name tells us this).

```
var relationships = Em.get(App.Parent, 'relationships');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zebalupoba/1/edit

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Apparently, the static property contains information different from what i wanted.